# Internal Error #3400 when trying to check in a visio file to a document library

Tags: document-library, visio-services, visio

Backstory:  For our company intranet we wanted to add an employee seating chart feature so that employees can see where other employees in the building sit.  I created a document library to store the floor plans as Visio files so that they can be viewed by the employees on another page using the Visio Web Access webpart.

Problem:  The initial save to the document library worked but whenever I try to check the Visio file into the document library it gives me the following error:

> Internal Error #3400 Action 1787: Check in file First try closing and
>   reopening the file.  Next try to restart Visio

I found a solution on the [Microsoft forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visiogeneral/thread/40aa1efe-a402-4fd0-af4b-9df49089a4f8/) saying that I need Visio Premium instead of Professional but I have Premium so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [blog entry](http://www.wahooga.com/2011/08/01/visio-2010sharepoint-2010-internal-error-3400-action-1787-check-in-file/) which talks about required fields being missing when trying to submit changes.  However, I looked at the default document library columns and none of them appeared to be required.  Finally, I checked the "Info" page in Visio itself where you have to check-in the document and I found a bunch of properties on the right that were not all filled in.

The image below shows the properties inside the red box.  I made sure that all of them were filled in and after that I no longer received an error when checking in the Visio drawing.

[image: Visio Page]

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer above may have solved the issue, the underlying problem is due to **Required List Content Types** that your company may have required for your Documents.

For SharePoint 2013 (*where I had the same issue*):

1) In the Document Library where you are storing the Visio file, click on the "**LIBRARY**" tab at the top of the screen and select "**Library Settings**".

2) Under "**Content Types**" select "**Document**" or "*Company* Document" or whatever the Default Content Type is.

3) You may see some Columns (Properties) which the Site Owner has determined are **Required**.  These are the Properties which must be populated for the Visio File itself in the Document Library.

4) Return to your Document Library and Select (checkmark) your Visio File.  Click on the "**FILES**" tab at the top of the screen and select "**Edit Properties**".

5) Any Line that has an asterisk (*) against it is a **Required Property**.

Populate all the "*" lines and you will no longer have the "**Internal Error #3400**" problem when Saving and Checking-In the Visio File to your SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to check in the file once I populated the required metadata. It would be much more helpful if Visio opened the document panel with the required fields as most other Office applications do.

Answer (score 0):

**Visio Internal error: #3400 Action 1005: Save As**

I just had this issue reoccur after more than 10 years ago while using Visio 2010. At the time the company moved everything to Sharepoint 2010 v3.  Simple solution then was removed Visio drawings from Sharepoint.

Today Jan 2023, after Googling this issue there was only a few posts on the issue, and none of the solution's seemed to apply to my case.

I shared the drawing with our IT guy, and he discovered something very strange in vsdx file.  There was a hidden object in the middle of the page.

[image]

Upon encircling the dot, the menu above displayed another menu item.  "Picture Format".  (Mind you there's no pictures in this drawing.)

With my interest peaked, I closed the .vsdx file and changed the file extension from .vsdx to .zip. Next, I opened it with my 7zip application and bingo every data point is visible as folders and file's. After drilling down in the Visio folder there were 3 subfiles marked with references to OLE. This has to be the issue. (This works on all Office Documents) With the issue discovered in my case, it's time to rename the file back to .vsdx and open and remove the object "Picture", save the changes and "Save As" pdf.

**Successful my error 3400** "Save As, PDF"

Hope this discovery and technic help's others.